# How to split a dataframe by using if condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

Hello, everyone. Does anybody know how to split __label__1 and __label__2 as index 1 and text data as index 2?

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('train.ft.txt',header=None,sep='\t',error_bad_lines=False)
for line in dataset:
idx[0]=[]
idx[1]=[]
if line.str.contains('__label__1' | '__label__2'):
    a=idx[0].append()
    # infile.append(a)
else:
    b=idx[1].append()
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work (runnable example):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df["0"] = ["__label__2 Amazing", "__label__1 test"]

df = df.merge(df["0"].apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'index_1':s.split(" ",1)[0], 'index_2':s.split(" ",1)[1]})),
    left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(df)
```

## Output:

```
                    0     index_1  index_2
0  __label__2 Amazing  __label__2  Amazing
1     __label__1 test  __label__1     test
```

Comment: Thank youu! I will try:)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to parse a file in fixed format. You can use the pd.read_fwf function as below:

#### **Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_fwf("SO_Answer.csv",colspecs=[(0,10),(11,-1)],header=None)
df1.head()
```

#### **Output:**

The output should look  like :

```
   0            1
0   __label__2  Stuning even for non gramer
1   __label__2  The best of sound track ever
2   __label__2  Amazing!The soundtrack is my fav
3   __label__1  Don't do it!! The high chair
4   __label__1  is compact but hard to clean is compact but ha...
```